# Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, oop

The following code will throw an error only for the `name` property.
It could be fixed by specifying `name` property as writable in `Object.create` arguments but **I'm trying to understand why is this happening**(and maybe there is a more elegant way to fix it).

```js
var BaseClass = function (data) {
  Object.assign(this, data);
}

var ExtendedClass = function () {
  BaseClass.apply(this, arguments);
}

ExtendedClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass);

console.log(new ExtendedClass({ type: 'foo' }));
new ExtendedClass({ name: 'foo' });
```

Comment: Because all functions have a native `name` property that returns the function's name. But, as is the case with JavaScript, inherited properties can be overwritten by creating new ones.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, thanks for the answer, that was obvious it's a shame that I didn't think about that. Is there a more robust way to bypass that error in class inheritance?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot modify the `name` property of a function. The descriptor says it is not `writable`...

```js
var BaseClass = function (data) {
  Object.assign(this, data);
};

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(BaseClass, 'name'));
```

But since it is `configurable`, you could use `Object.defineProperty()`.

```js
var BaseClass = function (data) {
  Object.assign(this, data);
};

Object.defineProperty(BaseClass, 'name', {
  writable: true,
  value: 'Foo'
});

console.log(BaseClass.name);
```

---

**EDIT**

I'm back! So... As I said previously in comments, I think I have identified your problem. I answered a bit too fast and did not see that your ES5 inheritance is wrong.

`ExtendedClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass);` is not what you want to do. Doing so means the prototype of `ExtendedClass` becomes a constructor function. This obviously generates an unexpected behavior.

```js
function BaseClass(data) {
  console.log(this instanceof BaseClass); // "this" is not an instance of "BaseClass"
  console.log(this instanceof Function); // "this" is a function
  console.log(this.name); // "this" is "BaseClass"
  
  Object.assign(this, data);
}

function ExtendedClass() {
  BaseClass.apply(this, arguments);
}
ExtendedClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass);

new ExtendedClass({ type: 'foo' });
```

In your code, `this` is a function and refers to `BaseClass`. That is why you are not allowed to modify its name...

In fact, when working with inheritance in JavaScript, you generally need these two lines:

```
ExtendedClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass.prototype);
ExtendedClass.prototype.constructor = ExtendedClass;
```

Here is a valid implementation:

```js
function BaseClass(data) {
  console.log(this instanceof BaseClass); // "this" is an instance of "BaseClass"
  console.log(this instanceof Function); // "this" is not a function
  console.log(this.name); // "this" has no name yet
  
  Object.assign(this, data);
}

function ExtendedClass() {
  BaseClass.apply(this, arguments);
}
ExtendedClass.prototype = Object.create(BaseClass.prototype);
ExtendedClass.prototype.constructor = ExtendedClass;

var instance = new ExtendedClass({ name: 'foo' });

console.log(instance.name); // foo
console.log(BaseClass.name); // BaseClass
console.log(ExtendedClass.name); // ExtendedClass
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I've actually had mentioned writable property modification in my question. But besides of that, I'm trying to find a more elegant way to handle it if there is any.

Comment: The best solution is probably to avoid the "name" keyword, just like you would avoid using reserved words like `var`, `typeof` or `arguments`... ;)

Comment: You're right, but `name` is pretty general property for classes and as in my case I'm creating a class for a backend response which contains `name` property and therefore, changing it will cause confusion for other developers.

Comment: I think I have just understood your question properly. I'll probably modify my answer to give you more insights... :)

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov: I have just modified my answer. Hope this helps... ;)

Comment: many thanks for your efforts, that is definitely more elegant than overriding the name property with `Object.defineProperty`. I've seen your's other answers, you are awesome guy, keep it up!

Comment: Wow! Thank you VERY MUCH for your upvotes, dude. I appreciate a lot. In fact, Stack Overflow is not always fair... You generally get more reputation with quick and short answers, but I often prefer to be slow and post long answers when the question is interesting. To be honest, this is not a lucrative business in terms of reputation points. I have posted some in-depth answers which received nothing. But at least, if it can help someone in the future, this is great. Happy JavaScripting! :)

Answer (score 56):

If you get this error in **Angular+Typescript+NgRX**:

You can use the spread operator to take a shallow copy of a readonly object to make it readable, however you may not want this depending on your situation.

```
let x = [...y];
```

If you're using Redux / NgRX, there's a chance your selector could be returning a readonly object with a reference to the store, which can throw exceptions when trying to alter that object property via template binding. Depending on your situation, you can take a deep copy to remove the store reference.

```
let x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(y));
```

Comment: I am getting this error in an angular+ngrx error, but what I do not understand why I get it for every object, even for objects not in the state or reducers.

Comment: This is so clever, thanks for saving my day

Answer (score 7):

Used ES7+ or TypeScript spread operator feature to overcome this

```
obj = { ...obj, name: { first: 'hey', last: 'there'} }
```

Answer (score 5):

The `name` is reserved property of `Function` object to which you are trying to set it in. You cannot set it.

documentation for name property is at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

Comment: But it works well with [ES6 classes](http://jsbin.com/quwivisiwi/1/edit?js,console), is there any way to make constructor functions to act like a class constructor in ES6?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you're using readonly object that can't be edited.
Use **cloneDeep** from lodash.

```
const x = cloneDeep(y);
```

where y is readonly object & use x instead of y in your code.

Answer (score 3):

If you get this error in **Angular+TypeScript**:

WRONG / INVALID:

**@Output** whatever_var = new EventEmitter();

GOOD / CORRECT:

**@Output()** whatever_var = new EventEmitter();

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this error once with Nestjs, and I fixed it by turning the property type to 'any'

```
type Product = {
  readonly owner: string;
};

const obj: Product = {
  owner: 'John',
};

(obj.owner as any) = 'James';
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue in Angular, while setting a local variable from ActivatedRoute's queryParams, and attempting to conditionally either override or merge... Duplicating beforehand did the trick:

```
updateQp(qp = {}, force = false) { 
    let qpLoc = Object.assign({}, this.queryParamsLocal)
    this.queryParamsLocal = force ? qp : Object.assign(qpLoc, qp)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to swop 2 elements in an array in redux. Here's a simple way of how I altered the redux state while avoiding the readonly issue:

```
let newData = []
let data = store.getState().events.value

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(i === fromIndex) {
    newData.push(data[toIndex])
  }else if(i === toIndex) {
    newData.push(data[fromIndex])
  }else {
    newData.push(data[i])
  }
}
this.setEventsData(newData)
```

The above code creates a new empty array. It then iterates through the readonly array and pushes each item into the new array. This effectively creates a new array with the items of the readonly array positioned in a different order. If you are having trouble editing the values, you could alter the above code and create a new object with the altered values and insert that into the position where you'd like to make the change.