# Randomizing elements in an array in Typescript giving error: TypeError: 0 is read-only

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, sorting

I have an array of objects, and I'd like to randomize the order of the elements.

So I have the following:

```
const animals  = data?.fetchAllAnimals;
let randomizeAnimals = animals.sort(()=> Math.random() -0.5 )
```

But I keep getting this error in firefox:
`TypeError: 0 is read-only`

and a different error in chrome:
`TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64957735/typeerror-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-0-of-object-object-array-in

Comment: It seems that the array has been frozen (or something similar) so that it cannot be changed. So enzou's solution should work.

Comment: Yes that worked! I just did 

```let randomizedAnimals = [...animals];
  randomizedAnimals.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
```
 and everything is working okay now