# Convert array assignment through object spread

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to convert the following assignment to something that uses object spread instead:

```
bData.steps[bStepKey].params= cData[cKey]
```

I have tried below with no luck.

```
bData= {...bData, steps:{ ...bData.steps[bStepKey], params: cData[cKey]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the spread operator, but if you really wanted to use it:

```
bData = { ...bData, steps: { ...bData.steps, [bstepKey]: { ...steps[bstepKey], params: cData[cKey] }}};
```

Although it's not useful at all in this situation as you don't need to spread anything - your initial approach is much better:

```
bData.steps[bStepKey].params= cData[cKey]
```

Comment: Compiler says cannot find name steps

Comment: Thank you I got it to work because of you. Didn’t know I had to put the index in a bracket.

Comment: By the way, JavaScript is interpreted not compiled.

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I’m using spread is because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288164/cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-name-of-object-object-object

Comment: Typescript is compiled though :)