# firebase storage file name change

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am a newbie to firebase and Javascript.
How do I change the file name to user's uid and save it to storage?
And I want to upload a file after successful registration. Should I write a function in createUserWithEmailAndPassword or onAuthStateChanged?

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    var file = evt.target.files[0];

    var metadata = {
      'contentType': file.type
    };

    var storage_ref = storage.ref();

    storage_ref.child('userImages/' + user.uid).put(file, metadata).then(function(snapshot) {

      snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        console.log('File available at', url);
        profile_url = url;

      });
    }).catch(function(error) {

      console.error('Upload failed:', error);

    });



  } // handleFileSelect

  document.getElementById('input_img').addEventListener('change',handleFileSelect, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the file name directly. But there is an indirect way to do that, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720390/how-to-change-name-of-file-in-javascript-from-input-file)

You want User's UID as file name but you won't get that in `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` so you need to add that logic into `onAuthStateChanged` method. But `onAuthStateChanged` get called every time whenever users login so you need to build some kind of logic to execute your file upload method only first time when user log in.

Answer (score 0):

To take an action in response to the user account being created, you can use `then`.

So something like:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...    
  }.then(function(credential) {
    var user = credential.user

    var file = evt.target.files[0];

    var metadata = {
      'contentType': file.type
    };

    var storage_ref = storage.ref();

    storage_ref.child('userImages/' + user.uid).put(file, metadata).then(function(snapshot) {

      snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        ...
```